# Combine 3 or more arrays (php)

Tags: php, arrays, transpose

Quick example:

```
$array_1 = [1, 2, 3];
$array_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$array_3 = ['white', 'red', 'blue'];
```

I need an array like:

```
$array_4 = [
    [1, 'a', 'white'],
    [2, 'b', 'red'],
    [3, 'c', 'blue']
]
```

Comment: Will the arrays always be of equal length?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860490/interleaving-multiple-arrays-into-a-single-array

Comment: @Aillyn I removed the "zip" tag. That's for zip files. Different languages call this a different thing. It could be seen as a transposition or, perhaps more accurately, a generalized inner product.

Comment: @Artefacto It was more of a test of my new retag button than anything else. It's been a while since you've got to 500 I guess...

Comment: @Ailyn You shouldn't use sock-puppet accounts (pessimopoppotamus). I hope at least you're using it to upvote yourself...

Comment: @Artefacto It doesn't say anywhere that I can't have more than one account. You can take it to the admins if you want. I never upvoted myself.

Comment: @Ailyn You're right, it's sort of permitted as long as you're not upvoting yourself (or upvoting someone else more than once). Sorry for the inconvenience. :p

Answer (score 7):

You mean something like Python's `zip()`? This will do:

```
$zipped = array_map(null, $array_1, $array_2, $array_3);
```

If you want a function that can do it with an arbitrary number of arrays, see: [Is there a PHP function like Python's zip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815162/is-there-a-php-function-like-pythons-zip/3451449#3451449)

Comment: What do you mean "with an arbitrary number of arrays"? `array_map` accepts an arbitrary number of arrays,

Comment: @Artefacto You are right I guess. Now that I think about, I don't know what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for a one-liner? I can't provide that, but this is my attempt:

```
$array_4=array();
for($i = 0 ; $i<count($array_1) ; ++$i) {
  $array_4[$i] = array($array_1[$i], $array_2[$i], $array_3[$i]);
}
```

This code of course assumes that all input arrays have the same lengths.

If you have more than 3 input arrays I would put them all in an array and foreach over it:

```
$all_arrays = array($aray_1, $array_2, ...);
$output_array=array();
for($i = 0 ; $i<count($array_1) ; ++$i) {
  $output_array[$i] = array();
  foreach($all_arrays as $input_array) {
    $output_array[$i][] = $input_array[$i];
  }
}
```

Comment: The prefix `++` is evil and apparently confusing you, silvo. Array indices start at `0`.

Comment: @You: In c++/C# it does not matter if pre or post increment is used in the for loop. Do you want to say that it matters in php? I think you are mistaken.

Comment: @Aillyn: Give me a chance to upskill myself. What exactly is incorrect there?

Comment: @silvo Your previous answer didn't work. This one still has problems. Try and use it with the OP's inputs. I removed my downvote though.

Comment: @Aillyn: Spotted the missing $s. Thanks.

Comment: @You - preincrement is good. It is slightly faster than post increment in PHP. In this case using either would give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear but:

If you want to combine all the values of 3 or more arrays into one array you can do this:

```
$array_4 = array_merge($array_1, $array_2, $array_3);
```

If you want to combine all those arrays into one you can do this:

```
$array_4[] = $array_1;
$array_4[] = $array_2;
$array_5[] = $array_3;
```

But I think you are really after for what Silvo posted above, hence +1 to him.

Answer (score -1):

Just a simple array_merge would do this.

Answer (score -3):

I think the easiest way, without using a bunch of array_X functions would be to simply "concatenate" them all into one array.

For instance

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3);
$arr2 = array(a,b,c);
$arr3 = array("red","white","blue");
$bigArray[] = $arr1;
$bigArray[] = $arr2;
$bigArray[] = $arr3;
```

Then you would have 1 Array containing three separate arrays, assuming that is what you're after.

$bigArray would look something like this

```
Array (
        0 Array (
           0 => 1
           1 => 2
           2 => 3
       )
        1 Array (
           0 => a
           1 => b
           2 => c
       )
        2 Array (
           0 => red
           1 => white
           2 => blue
       )
)
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants.