# How to pass dynamically created arguments (variable variables arrays) to function in php?

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables, parameter-passing

I have a custom function `array_sequence_merge()`. With the help of `func_get_args()`, any number of arguments can be passed to the function as long as they are all ARRAYS.

**The problem** is, the arrays that need to be passed into function are created dynamically with WHILE loop of unknown size:

```
while($n < count($site)) {
    $siten = $site[$n];
    $sql = "SELECT url FROM `".$$siten->domain."`";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        ${$siten."_url_list"} = $row['url'];
    }
}
```

So. for example, if there 3 elements in `$site` array, the resulting 3 arrays will be:

```
$element1_url_list
$element2_url_list
$element3_url_list
```

Now they have to be passed to `array_sequence_merge()` function to get:

```
array_sequence_merge($element1_url_list, $element2_url_list, $element3_url_list);
```

Each time the amount of elements in `$site` array is different, and so is the amount of dynamically created `XXXXX_url_list` arrays.

**Question:** How do I pass those array variables into the function?

The way I approached it, was to store dynamically created array variable name in a temporary array right after it is created in a WHILE loop. But I am not sure what to  with it next... If only I could do some kind of "argument list concatenation", something like:

```
$arguments = $temporary_array[0];
while($n < count($temporary_array)) {
    $arguments .= ",".$temporary_array[$n];
}

array_sequence_merge($arguments);
```

Just not sure how to do it right...

Comment: what is the array_sequence_merge() and what does it do?

Comment: it only accepts one-dimensional arrays as arguments and passing a single multi-dimensional array as an argument will not work. Here is the [link to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482028/explain-how-this-custom-function-works-php)

Comment: `$n` is never incremented and `$site` is never altered, so your snippet will suffer from an infinite loop.  We do not have a [mcve] here, so your question is Unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/de/function.call-user-func-array.php) like this:

```php
call_user_func_array('array_sequence_merge', $arguments);
```

with $arguments being your array of parameters.

Then every element of the array is handled as a separate parameter of "array_sequence_merge".

**Edit**
To achieve something like

```php
array_sequence_merge($element1_url_list, $element2_url_list, $element3_url_list, ...);
```

you have to change the code like this:

```php
$arguments = [];
while($n < count($site)) {
    $siten = $site[$n];
    $sql = "SELECT url FROM `".$$siten->domain."`";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        $arguments[] = $row['url'];
    }
}

// $result contains the return value of the array_sequence_merge function call
$result = call_user_func_array('array_sequence_merge', $arguments);
```

So basically instead of creating $elementN_url_list variables write them into the array $arguments and pass it to call_user_func_array as second parameter.

Comment: $arguments is array consisting of parameters variables names and not the parameters itself, will it still work?

Comment: Doesn't answer the actual question which is how to use the function with a bunch of variable variables, not an array

Comment: I just tried it and it only passes string values of $temporary_array (or $arguments in your answer) elements and not the variables of arrays that needed.

Comment: @Acidon just add your arguments to an array, not a comma separated string (then pass it into the example in this answer)

Comment: @RobbieAverill $temporary_array IS array ;)

Comment: @RobbieAverill read comment #3 with the results of that attempt

Comment: I suggest you set up an online example with mocked input and explain your expected output accurately

Comment: @RobbieAverill function expects to get list of **arrays** as arguments (eg `$array1, $array2,..,$arrayn` and not just a single array, which elements are **strings** `"array1", "array2",..., "arrayn"` . Not sure if I need to make an online example to illustrate it

Comment: What's the expected output or way of handling those arrays? Getting them in is not a problem

Comment: I edited my answer to make more clear how it should be done. If that still does not solve your problem, I probably misunderstood your question. ;-)

Comment: @TobiasXy Hi tobias, sorry I guess my question post is confusing :(( In particular the part where I use WHILE in place of FOR.. The WHILE loop in example in question loops more then ones, each time generating different sql query and different array with results, and then I need to pass those arrays into function, each array as separate argument. I don't need to pass array elements as arguments, I need to pass multiple arrays instead.

Comment: @RobbieAverill "Getting them in" is what this whole question is about... I beginning to think that the only way to handle my problem is to rewrite target function to intake one multidimensional array instead of multiple single-dimension arrays. Link to function is in the comment to question.

Comment: But that is exactly what call_user_func_array does (not to be confused with "call_user_func"!!). It takes a single array as second argument and passes every element of that array as a single argument. So what you have to do is to create one twodimensional array of all your parameters and pass it to call_user_func_array, which will pass multiple single-dimensional arrays as separate parameters to you function. Also check the documentation of this function (see link in the first line of my answer)