# How to Combine two arrays randomly in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random

How to combine two arrays into single one and i am requesting this in such a way that the 3rd combination array should contains one value from one array and the next one from other array and so on.. or ( it could be random)
ex:

```
$arr1 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$arr2 = (10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
```

and combined array

```
$arr3 = (1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30, ...);
```

Comment: Any difference with the count of array elements?

Comment: the output you show is not random but [a1,b1,a2,b2,…,an,bn]. In other words, the elements from the source arrays a and b are added in an alternating fashion to the resulting array in the order in which they appear in the source arrays

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815162/is-there-a-php-function-like-pythons-zip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also made a function for fun that will produce the exact output you had in your question. It will work regardless of the size of the two arrays.

```
function FosMerge($arr1, $arr2) {
    $res=array();
    $arr1=array_reverse($arr1);
    $arr2=array_reverse($arr2);
    foreach ($arr1 as $a1) {
        if (count($arr1)==0) {
            break;
        }
        array_push($res, array_pop($arr1));
        if (count($arr2)!=0) {
            array_push($res, array_pop($arr2));
        }
    }
    return array_merge($res, $arr2);
}
```

Answer (score 18):

If it can be random, this will solve your problem:

```
$merged = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
shuffle($merged);
```

Answer (score 4):

This will return a random array:

```
$merged = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
shuffle($merged);
```

Comment: shuffle itself will only return a boolean true/false

Comment: No, it won't. shuffle() doesn't return an array so your method will throw the merged array into the mist of void.

Comment: Ah yes. I forgot about that (oops). Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

```
sort($arr3 = array_merge($arr1, $arr2));
```

`array_merge()` will merge your arrays into one. `sort()` will sort the combined array.

If you want it random instead of sorted:

```
shuffle($arr3 = array_merge($arr1, $arr2));
```

`$arr3` contains the array you're looking for.

Comment: sort and shuffle return a bool, the passed (referenced) array is manipulated directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<?php
arr3 = array_merge ($arr1 , $arr2 );
print_r(arr3);
?>
```

which will output in

```
$arr3 = (1,2,3,4,5,10,20,30,40,50)
```