# Array to CSV file for vertical layout and failed to put the header row

Tags: php, csv

I have a problem to create a horizontal layout for the csv

here is an array which I have convert it to json-format

```
{"datetime":["2000-01-01","2000-01-02","2000-01-03","2000-01-04","2000-01-05","2000-01-06","2000-01-07","2000-01-08","2000-01-09","2000-01-10","2000-01-11","2000-01-12","2000-01-13","2000-01-14","2000-01-15","2000-01-16","2000-01-17","2000-01-18","2000-01-19","2000-01-20","2000-01-21","2000-01-22","2000-01-23","2000-01-24","2000-01-25","2000-01-26","2000-01-27","2000-01-28","2000-01-29","2000-01-30","2000-01-31","2000-02-01","2000-02-02","2000-02-03","2000-02-04","2000-02-05","2000-02-06","2000-02-07","2000-02-08","2000-02-09","2000-02-10","2000-02-11","2000-02-12","2000-02-13","2000-02-14","2000-02-15","2000-02-16","2000-02-17","2000-02-18","2000-02-19","2000-02-20","2000-02-21","2000-02-22","2000-02-24","2000-02-25","2000-02-26","2000-02-27","2000-02-28","2000-02-29","2000-03-01","2000-03-02","2000-03-03","2000-03-04","2000-03-05","2000-03-06","2000-03-07","2000-03-08","2000-03-09","2000-03-10","2000-03-11","2000-03-12","2000-03-13","2000-03-14","2000-03-15","2000-03-16","2000-03-17","2000-03-18","2000-03-19","2000-03-22","2000-03-23","2000-03-24","2000-03-28","2000-03-29","2000-03-30","2000-03-31","2000-04-01","2000-04-02","2000-04-03","2000-04-04","2000-04-05","2000-04-06","2000-04-07","2000-04-08","2000-04-09","2000-04-10","2000-04-11","2000-04-12","2000-04-13","2000-04-14","2000-04-15","2000-04-16","2000-04-17","2000-04-18","2000-04-19","2000-04-20","2000-04-21","2000-04-22","2000-04-23","2000-04-24","2000-04-25","2000-04-26","2000-04-27","2000-04-28","2000-04-29","2000-04-30","2000-05-01","2000-05-02","2000-05-03","2000-05-04","2000-05-05","2000-05-06","2000-05-07","2000-05-08","2000-05-09","2000-05-10","2000-05-11","2000-05-12","2000-05-13","2000-05-14","2000-05-15","2000-05-16","2000-05-17","2000-05-18","2000-05-19","2000-05-20","2000-05-21","2000-05-22","2000-05-23","2000-05-24","2000-05-25","2000-05-26","2000-05-27","2000-05-28","2000-05-29","2000-05-30","2000-05-31","2000-06-01","2000-06-02","2000-06-03","2000-06-04","2000-06-05","2000-06-06","2000-06-07","2000-06-08","2000-06-09","2000-06-10","2000-06-11","2000-06-12","2000-06-13","2000-06-14","2000-06-15","2000-06-16","2000-06-17","2000-06-18","2000-06-19","2000-06-20","2000-06-21","2000-06-22","2000-06-23","2000-06-24","2000-06-25","2000-06-26","2000-06-27","2000-06-28","2000-06-29","2000-06-30","2000-07-01","2000-07-02","2000-07-03","2000-07-04","2000-07-05","2000-07-06","2000-07-07","2000-07-08","2000-07-09","2000-07-10","2000-07-11","2000-07-12","2000-07-13","2000-07-14","2000-07-15","2000-07-16","2000-07-17","2000-07-18","2000-07-19","2000-07-20"],"Reservoir Level":["102.95","103.01","103.05","102.93","102.78","102.83","102.78","102.87","102.92","102.97","103.02","103.05","103.29","103.3","103.29","103.15","103","102.92","102.95","102.98","102.9","102.8","102.8","102.81","102.86","102.9","102.92","102.94","102.96","102.98","102.99","102.99","102.3","103","103.02","103.03","103.04","103.05","103.05","103.06","103.1","103.15","103.19","103.19","103.2","103.3","103.32","103.33","103.34","103.19","102.98","102.89","102.89","102.91","102.96","103.05","103.06","103.07","103.27","103.31","103.28","103.12","102.95","102.94","102.97","102.98","103.02","103.02","103.08","103.14","103.18","103.54","103.57","103.48","103.35","103.21","103.12","103.2","103.3","103.38","103.4","103.4","103.4","103.4","103.4","103.34","103.34","103.27","103.27","103.28","103.28","103.3","103.3","103.3","103.3","103.25","103.2","103.2","103.14","103.14","103.1","103.1","103","103","103.25","103.25","103.35","103.35","103.45","103.45","103.5","103.5","103.46","103.46","103.37","103.37","103.26","103.26","103.22","103.22","103.26","103.31","103.31","103.49","103.49","103.34","103.34","103.19","103.19","103.21","103.21","103.27","103.27","103.33","103.37","103.37","103.42","103.42","103.33","103.33","103.26","103.26","103.19","103.19","103.35","103.35","103.48","103.48","103.55","103.55","103.55","103.6","103.46","103.46","103.46","103.33","103.33","103.33","103.62","103.62","103.62","103.62","103.6","103.5","103.5","103.38","103.38","103.24","103.24","103.26","103.26","103.3","103.3","103.2","103.2","103.16","103.23","103.23","103.26","103.26","103.29","103.29","103.31","103.31","103.32","103.32","103.35","103.35","103.37","103.42","103.42","103.3","103.3","103.25","103.25","103.28","103.28","103.3","103.3","103.31","103.31","103.25","103.25","103.18","103.18","103.18","103.18","103.22","103.12","103.13","103.14","103.16","103.23","103.65","103.52","104.03","103.84","103.68","103.59","103.45","103.31","103.2","103.11","103.13","103.15","103.19","103.22","103.25","103.27","103.29","103.3","103.32","103.24","103.13","103.12","103.17","103.21","103.25","103.15","103.04","103.07","103.09","103.1","103.11","103.11","103.11","103.1","103.05","103.08","103.1","103.11","103.11","103.11","103.1","103.1","103.11","103.13"],"Rainfall":[null,"14.5","4.5","7","2.5","54",null,"18","2",null,"1",null,"24.5","9",null,null,null,null,null,"0.5",null,null,null,null,"10.5",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"5",null,null,null,"17.5","7.5",null,null,"7","20",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"5","10","9.5","0","0","45","0","42","0","0","0","0","2.5","27.5","0","29","39","2","93","6","0","0","14","0","8.5","0","43.5","31.5","0","0","32","32","0","0","2","2","14","14","20","20","4","4","0","0","5.5","5.5","0","0","17.5","17.5","0","0","16","16","0","0","14","14","0","0","0.5","0.5","0","0","0","0","0","0","8","8","3.5","3.5","69.5","69.5","0","0","0","0","39.5","39.5","5","5","9","9","1","1","0","0","6.5","6.5","11.5","11.5","14.5","14.5","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","21.5","21.5","21.5","0","0","0","0","0","0","54.5","54.5","0","0","14.5","14.5","12","12","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","31.5","31.5","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","24.5","24.5","0","0","18","18","0","0","12.5","12.5","6.5","6.5","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0.5","0","0","12.5","1","57.5","0","63","0","0","40","5.5","0","0","0","0","0","0.5","0.5","0","0","0","0","12.5","2.5","0.5","1","27","11","3.5","13","0","4.5","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1.5","0","0","0","0","2","9.5"]}
```

and here I have a develop a simple function to output it as csv

```
function convert_to_csv($input_array, $output_file_name, $delimiter) {
    $temp_memory = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

    foreach ($input_array as $key => $set) {
        fputcsv($temp_memory, $set, $delimiter, '"');
    }
    fseek($temp_memory, 0);
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $output_file_name . '";');
    fpassthru($temp_memory);
}
```

here the layout that i don't want it to be

[image]

and this is the layout that I want it to be

[image]

as you can see I failed to find a way to put the header row. Appreciate your helps. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need transposition.

```
foreach($input_array as $key=>$set){
  foreach($set as $row=>$val){
    $lines[$row][$key] = $val;
  }
}
```

For `input_array` like:

```
{"datetime":["2000-01-01","2001-01-01"], "Resovior":[1,2], "RainFall":[2,2]}
```

will produce `$lines` like

```
$lines[0]: {"datetime": "2000-01-01", "Resovior": 1, "RainFall": 2}
$lines[1]: {"datetime": "2001-01-01", "Resovior": 2, "RainFall": 2}
```

Keep in mind that every element of `$lines` refers to one **row** in your file, and its' elements are the **columns**.

Then you can put rows like this:

```
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
  fputcsv($temp_memory,$line,$delimeter,"'");
}
```

The way to add a header is the same.

```
$header = array("DateTime", "Revisior", "Rainfall");
fputcsv($temp_memory, $header, $delimeter, "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output file is wrong formatted, must be like that:

```
DateTime;Reservoir;Rainfall;
date1;res1;rain1;
date2;res2;rain2;
date3;res3;rain3;
```

but your current file looks like this one:

```
date1;date2;date3;
res1;res2;res3;
rain1;rain2;rain3;
```

You must iterate trough array recursively in order to set the correct format.

A possible solution (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6600130/3518053 ) :

```
$fh = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

// write out the headers
fputcsv($fh, array_keys($data));

// write out the data    
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['dates']); $i++) {
    $temp = array($data['dates'][$i], $data['type1'][$i], $data['type2'][$i]);
    fputcsv($fh, $temp);
}
```

Regards

Comment: is there any other library to change the way the `fputcsv()` works?

Comment: You don't need to cfhange fputcsv() way, only take care about writting csv headers first and below data in the right format. Try my example for getting ideas and post results.