# How to display two arrays in one foreach loop?

Tags: php

am storing two arrays in one column.first one is images stored as image1**image2**...etc and second one is descriptions as description1**description2**...etc. i want to use these two set of arrays in one foreach loop.Please help.

Comment: update your question and show what you have and what you expected..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815162/is-there-a-php-function-like-pythons-zip

Comment: Show us your code, the output and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem possible by foreach loop. Instead try using for loop. If you are sure both your arrays are of the same size, then try using following code:

```
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof(array1); $i++) {
     echo $arrray1[$i];
     echo $arrray2[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just reference the key:

```
foreach ($images as $key => $val) {
    echo '<img src="' . $val . '" alt="' . $descriptions[$key] . '" /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `foreach`, but you can use `for` and indexed access like so.

```
$count = count($images);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $image = $images[$i];
    $description = $descriptions[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `array_combine` to combine the two arrays and then use a foreach loop.

```
$images = array('image1', 'image2', ...);
$descriptions = array('description1', 'description2', ...);

foreach (array_combine($images, $descriptions) as $image => $desc) {
  echo $image, $desc;
}
```