# How to merge arrays without overwriting its index in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, transpose

I have this array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Name
        [1] => Email
        [2] => Address
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => vanson
        [1] => dhmax@pan.com
        [2] => gurgaon
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => john
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => sdf
        [1] => sdfsdf
        [2] => sdfsd
    )

)
```

and i want this

```
Array
(       [0] => Name
        [1] => Email
        [2] => Address
        [0] => vanson
        [1] => dhmax@pan.com
        [2] => gurgaon
        [0] => john
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [0] => sdf
        [1] => sdfsdf
        [2] => sdfsd
  )
```

**WITHOUT OVERWRITING ITS INDEX**

or i want to create dynamic arrays and put the same indexed values into individual arrays.something like this

```
$arr_1 = array(
                    [0] => Name
                    [1] => vanson
                    [2] => john
                    [3] => sdf
                    )
  $arr_2 = array(
                    [0] => Email
                    [1] => dhmax@pan.com
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => sdfsdf
                    )
   $arr_3 = array(
                    [0] => Address
                    [1] => gurgaon
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => sdfsd
                    )
```

Arrays are created on the basis of the count of 1st indexed array.(Ex if 0th index has array of 4 then 4 arrays should be created.)

Comment: You can't have more than one value for the same index. How would you be able to retrieve them individually if you did? Read up on arrays and how they work.

Comment: As i have written in last code. I have to merge same indexed array values into one and other indexed array values into another array. So i thought if i merge all array index->values into one and then grab same indexed values into array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) cannot have multiple values with the same index, so your first suggestion is not possible.

However, the second option can be achieved with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map), by passing a `null` value as the callback parameter.  Here's a convenient helper function that will do it (based on [this excellent answer by Tadeck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815162/is-there-a-php-function-like-pythons-zip/8375865#8375865) to another question):

```
function array_transpose( $array ) {
    $array = array_merge( array( null ), array_values( $array ) );
    return call_user_func_array( 'array_map', $array );
}

$columns = array_transpose( $rows );
```

([demo on codepad.org](http://codepad.org/eCRSExWN))

Answer (score -1):

PHP have inbuilt function called [array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/array_chunk),You can use it like this-

```
$array = Array(Array(1=>'Name',2=>'Email'),Array(1=>'suresh',2=>'email@gmail.com'));        
echo "<pre>";print_r(array_chunk($array,1,true));
Output-
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => Name [2] => Email ) ) [1] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [1] => suresh [2] => email@gmail.com ) ) )
```

Comment: This doesn't look like what the OP wants to do to me. He already has an array of rows, and he wants to obtain the columns.

Comment: @udgeetpatel : you ask either of two output, with array_chunk() you can achieve second output.