# PHP: Get result from arrays.

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry for the title. its little difficult for me to explain. I've spent almost few hours to figure this out, but failed. So I'm posting it here.

I have following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => p
            [1] => q
            [2] => r
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => w
            [1] => x
            [2] => y
            [3] => z
        )

)
```

The array could have any number of elements.

What i need to do is create another array based on above array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => p
            [2] => w
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => q
            [2] => x
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => r
            [2] => y
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Z
        )

)
```

Any hints will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what does "based on above array" means?

Comment: foreach($array as $var)  {$yourOtherArray[] = $var;}

Comment: Take a look here. The only difference is that each of your args is just an element of the first array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815162/is-there-a-php-function-like-pythons-zip

Comment: from where I see it 2 nested loops could do the trick. If you could show us some code produced during the almost few hours you tried, that may help us finding where you're exactly struggling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If PHP < 5.5 or you don't want to use array_column-solution

```
$newArray = array();

foreach($array as $row)
     foreach($row as $key => $value){
         if (!isset($newArray[$key]))
             $newArray[$key] = array();
         $newArray[$key][] = $value;
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade to PHP 5.5 if you aren't already on it, then use [`array_column`](http://php.net/array-column)

Comment: Can you tell me what he wants to do?

Comment: Looks like he needs array of arrays where each "sub-array" holds the elements that have same index in source array.

Comment: Up gradation is really a solution?

Comment: Exactly what @DKasipovic said. OP is trying to get the columns of the array.

Comment: @DushyantJoshi ***YES!*** You should *always* run the latest (stable) versions of things, if for nothing else than for the security fixes, but mostly for all the new features and improvements!

Comment: @DKasipovic Me too. Apparently, this is too simple, it cannot possibly be the right answer...

Answer (score 2):

Just try with [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive):

```
$input  = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['p', 'q', 'r'],
    ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
];
$output = [];


array_walk_recursive($input, function($value, $index) use (&$output) {
    if (!isset($output[$index])) {
        $output[$index] = [];
    }

    $output[$index][] = $value;
});
```

Output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'p' (length=1)
      2 => string 'w' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'b' (length=1)
      1 => string 'q' (length=1)
      2 => string 'x' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'c' (length=1)
      1 => string 'r' (length=1)
      2 => string 'y' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'z' (length=1)
```

Comment: The whole condition block can be safely removed. https://3v4l.org/GTjk1