# Make a json object with two arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

By getting query from MySQL, I have 2 arrays like this:
for  example:
Sig:{a,b,c,d,e}
T:{1,2,3,4,5}

Now, in PHP, I want to merge these two arrays and have an array like: {(a,1),(b,2),(c,3),(d,4),(e,5)} then, show it as a JSON in order to draw chart by the Google visualize API.

How can I do this?

```
    $data = array();
    $data['cols'] = array(
                    array('id' => 'Sig','label' => 'Sig', 'type' => 'string'),
                    array('id' => 'T','label' => 'Time', 'type' => 'string')
                    );

   $rows = array();
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $temp = array();

//changing the string (data in MySQL) into array of float for column Sig
   $csvdata = $r['Sig'];
   $a = explode(',', $csvdata);

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($a);$i++)
    {
        $floa[]=floatval($a[$i]);
                }

//changing the string (data in MySQL) into array of float for column T
   $csvdata = $r['T'];
   $s = explode(',', $csvdata);
   for($i=0;$i<sizeof($s);$i++)
    {
        $flos[]=floatval($s[$i]);
                }

   function toArr(){
   return func_get_args();
   }

    $c = array_map ('toArr',$floa,$flos);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $c);

    $rows[]= array('c' => $temp);
    }

  $data['rows'] = $rows;
  echo json_encode($data);
```

This is the output:

```
{"cols":[{"id":"Sig","label":"Sig","type":"string"},{"id":"T","label":"Time",‌​"type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":[[0,0],[1.2490004e-5,2.0545915e-5],[2.497876‌​8e-5,4.108994e-5],[3.7465044e-5,6.16302e-5]]}]}]}
```

but I need it to be like this:

```
   {"cols":[{"id":"Sig","label":"Sig","type":"string"},{"id":"T","label":‌"Time",‌"type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":1.2490004e-5},{"v":2.0545915e-5}]},‌{"c":[{"v":2.497876‌8e-5},{"v":4.108994e-5}]},{"c":[{"v":3.7465044e-5},{"v":6.16302e-5}]}]}
```

Comment: Your desired output is not valid JSON. It's apparently an object since it's in curly braces (`{`...`}`), but it has no keys. It contains pairs of numbers in parentheses, which is not valid for anything in JSON.  Could you please post a valid goal output?

Comment: This question is not terribly clear because there is no sample input / [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for any number of arrays:

```
<?php
function toArr(){
    return func_get_args();
}

$a = array ('a','b','c','d','e');
$b = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$c = array_map ('toArr',$a,$b);
var_dump(json_encode($c));
?>
```

Edit: 
I forgot about the json encode part. You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: thanks but how can I have an array of smaller arrays. for instance: I want to have these arrays (a,1) (b,2) ...

Comment: I want to draw chart by these spots as the X and Y

Comment: @nazanin the result of the above code is `[["a",1],["b",2],["c",3],["d",4],["e",5]]`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: this is fine, but this is the json of this code {"cols":[{"id":"Sig","label":"Signal","type":"string"},{"id":"T","label":"Time","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":[[0,0],[1.2490004e-5,2.0545915e-5],[2.4978768e-5,4.108994e-5],[3.7465044e-5,6.16302e-5]]}]}]}

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#zip) refer to that array operation as *zip*. [PHP can zip arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2815567/770127) via `array_map`. Use `json_encode` to convert the zipped array to JSON.

```
function zipEncode($a, $b) {
  return json_encode(array_map(null, $a, $b));
}
```

For example `zipEncode(['a', 'b'], [1, 2])` returns `'[["a",1],["b",2]]'`

A standalone zip function accepting any number of arrays could be:

```
function zip() {
  return call_user_func_array('array_map', array_merge([null], func_get_args()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want `{(a,1),(b,2),(c,3),(d,4),(e,5)}`, I assume, since you asked for JSON, what you really want is this: `[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3],[d,4],[e,5]]`, where `a`..`e` are hopefully numbers.

You can use `array_map` with a null function to zip arrays together in this fashion.  Here's an example (with strings for the letters):

```
 $letters = array('a','b','c','d','e');
 $numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5);
 print(json_encode(array_map(null, $letters, $numbers)));
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**

Oh, sorry. Try this [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and this [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: the result is like this: $c=['a','1','c','3'] but I need it to be {(a,1),(b,2),(c,3),(d,4),(e,5)}

Comment: thanks but this is not what I'm thinking. This is like {a,1,b,2,c,3,d,4}

Comment: these are the spots of my chart (x and Y)