# Mixing two arrays together in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I have two arrays like this:

```
$array1(one,  two, three);
$array2(four, five, six);
```

And I want the result to be like this:

```
[0] -> one four
[1] -> two five
[2] -> three six
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i suggest doing it with code. but if you prefer some other method ...

Comment: @AmitThakur are you sure about that - hint- no

Comment: Possible duplicate to [Is there a php function like python's zip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815162/is-there-a-php-function-like-pythons-zip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_map` function providing your two arrays in parameter :

```
<?php
$array1=Array("one",  "two", "three");
$array2=Array("four", "five", "six");

$res=array_map(function($r1, $r2) {return "$r1 $r2";}, $array1, $array2);
print_r($res);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => one four
    [1] => two five
    [2] => three six
)
```

Comment: Yes, array_map seems to work exactly as I wanted. For some reason I did not find this on PHP manual. Only combine, merge and so on. Thank you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function array_interlace() { 
$args = func_get_args(); 
$total = count($args); 

if($total < 2) { 
    return FALSE; 
} 

$i = 0; 
$j = 0; 
$arr = array(); 

foreach($args as $arg) { 
    foreach($arg as $v) { 
        $arr[$j] = $v; 
        $j += $total; 
    } 

    $i++; 
    $j = $i; 
} 

ksort($arr); 
return array_values($arr); 
}
$array1=array('one',  'two', 'three');
$array2=array('four', 'five',' six');
print_r(array_interlace($array1,$array2));
```