# How to concatenate two arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays generating from two sql queries as $array_1 and $array_2. both contain [0] indexes. I want to join them with indexes [0],[1] and so on... So can any one help me on how to **concatenate** two arrays in php

Comment: Have you tried `$newArray = array_merge($array_1, $array_2);` or `$newArray = $array_1 + $array_2;`

Answer (score 6):

**[array_merge — Merge one or more arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)**

*Description*

```
array array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )
```

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values
>   of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the
>   resulting array.
>
> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.
>
> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with
>   incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.

---

**Zipping arrays:**

If you want `[0]` to be `array1[0]` and `[1]` to be `array2[0]` etc., you can zip the arrays;

[Is there a php function like python's zip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815162/is-there-a-php-function-like-pythons-zip)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for `array_merge`?

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp

In your case: `array_merge($array_1,$array_2)`

Comment: Surely better to post a reference to the actual [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), rather than to a third party (with a dubious reputation) like w3schools

Comment: Didn't know about w3schools reputation, thanks for the heads up. Luckily another user already provided the official docs.

Comment: @Mark Baker I honestly don't know what people have against W3schools. They provide concise and useful - certainly if you're a beginner - intros to a lot of tech. Incidentally, using the + operator will ignore any value in the second array if it has a key present in the first array, even if the key is numeric.

Comment: @GeoffKendall - In the past (I don't know if it's still true), w3schools was full of inaccuracies and recommendations that went against good practise.... that's what a lot of people have against w3schools

Comment: @GeoffKendall - But the actual PHP Docs will always be a better recommendation than a 3rd party site for information on a basic php function

Comment: @Mark Baker Well, not always - the PHP docs sometimes miss showing a straightforward example. Have to admit I've just suggested a clarification over at W3schools on this particular operator's write up 'though. All the same, it's a free service and was useful to me when I was getting started - obviously, SO is the place once you're up and running.

Comment: I can't think of many php functions that are missing examples; certainly array_merge has a number, including showing the index changes.... it is some of the best documentation you can find for almost any programming language