# how to create one table in multiple foreach?

Tags: php, html

I am building add to card codes with php mailer.

I am creating send shopping cart items with email.
There are in mail body five foreach array, i need create one table in there but table rows can not correct, how can I fix it?

```
    $mail->Body = "<div class='container-fullwidth'>
  <h2>Sipariş Özeti</h2>
  <hr>
<div class='table-responsive'>          
  <table width='100%' class='table table-striped'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><h2>Ürün</h2></th>
        <th><h2>Gramaj</h2></th>
        <th><h2>Adet</h2></th>
        <th><h2>Birim Fiyat</h2></th>
        <th><h2>Birim Tutar</h2></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";

    $mail->Body .= "<tr align='left'>";
    foreach ($urun_adi as $urun) {
        $mail->Body .= "<td bgcolor='#f0f8ff'><h2>$urun</h2></td>";
    }
    foreach ($gramaj_adetler as $gramaj_adet) {
        $mail->Body .= "<td bgcolor='#f0f8ff'><h2>$gramaj_adet</h2></td>";
    }
    foreach ($toplamadet as $toplamA) {
        $mail->Body .= "<td bgcolor='#f0f8ff'><h2>$toplamA</h2></td>";
    }
    foreach ($trBirimfiyat as $trBirimF) {
        $mail->Body .= "<td bgcolor='#f0f8ff'><h2>$trBirimF</h2></td>";
    }
    foreach ($trBirimtutar as $trBirimT) {
        $mail->Body .= "<td bgcolor='#f0f8ff'><h2>$trBirimT</h2></td>";
    }a
    $mail->Body .= "</tr>";
    $mail->Body .= "</tbody></table></div></div>"; //close table
    echo "</tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try this

```
$mail->Body = "<div class='container-fullwidth'>
<h2>Sipariş Özeti</h2>
<hr>
<div class='table-responsive'>          
  <table width='100%' class='table table-striped'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><h2>Ürün</h2></th>
        <th><h2>Gramaj</h2></th>
        <th><h2>Adet</h2></th>
        <th><h2>Birim Fiyat</h2></th>
        <th><h2>Birim Tutar</h2></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";

    for($i=0; $i < count($urn_adi); $i++) {
        $mail->Body .= "<tr align='left'>";
        $mail->Body .= "<td bgcolor='#f0f8ff'><h2>$urun_adi[$i]</h2></td>";
        $mail->Body .= "<td bgcolor='#f0f8ff'><h2>$gramaj_adetler[$i]</h2></td>";
        $mail->Body .= "<td bgcolor='#f0f8ff'><h2>$toplamadet[$i]</h2></td>";
        $mail->Body .= "<td bgcolor='#f0f8ff'><h2>$trBirimfiyat[$i]</h2></td>";
        $mail->Body .= "<td bgcolor='#f0f8ff'><h2>$trBirimtutar[$i]</h2></td>";
        $mail->Body .= "</tr>";
    }
    $mail->Body .= "</tbody></table></div></div>"; //close table
    echo "</tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
```

Comment: so approve answer as it will help some one else quickly

Answer (score 1):

You should pack your Items into an Array in a Format like this:

```
$basket = array(array('quantity' => 1, 'articleid' => 123, 'foo' => 'something'),
                array('quantity' => 2, 'articleid' => 234, 'foo' => 'something'),
                array('quantity' => 3, 'articleid' => 345, 'foo' => 'something'));
```

When you have this Format, you can easily create a List with it.

```
echo '<table>';
foreach($basket as $item){
 echo '<tr><td>'.$item['quantity'].'</td><td>'.$item['articleid'].'</td><td>'.$item['foo'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

So I would suggest you to first merge these Arrays into one.

Answer (score 1):

You can 'zip' the arrays (as long as they are the same length), and then iterate through.

```
<?php
$letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$zipped = array_map(null, $letters, $numbers);

$out = '<table>';
foreach($zipped as $array) {
    $out .= '<tr>';
    $out .=   '<td>' . $array[0] . '</td>';
    $out .=   '<td>' . $array[1] . '</td>';
    $out .= '</tr>';
}
$out .= '</table>';
```

Table result:

```
a   1
b   2
c   3
d   4
```

Zipped array:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'b',
    1 => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'c',
    1 => 3,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'd',
    1 => 4,
  ),
)
```

Comment: You can combine multiple arrays like that.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2815567/3392762

Comment: Thanks for the Info with array_map()! :)

Comment: Yep not intuitive, but there's an example given in the manual.