# Is there an alternative for array_merge?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.4

The problem is, I'm not getting the expected results of my array code.

I've tried doing the array_merge, but all it does was to merge all the arrays.

```
$medicine_order = $request['medicine_id'];

        array:3 [▼
          0 => "25"
          1 => "32"
          2 => "30"
      ]

      $medicine_quantity = $request['medicine_quantity'];

      array:3 [▼
          0 => "3"
          1 => "10"
          2 => "6"
      ]

      $count = 0;
      foreach ($medicine_order as $id) {
        $item = new Historyitem;
        $item->medicine_id = $id;

        foreach ($medicine_quantity as $id2) {
            $item->historyitem_quantity = $id2;
        }
        $item->save();
        $count++;
    }
```

I wanted to store these values in my DB.

```
array:3 [▼
          0 => "25"
          1 => "3"
      ]
 array:3 [▼
          0 => "32"
          1 => "10"
      ] 
array:3 [▼
          0 => "30"
          1 => "6"
      ]
```

but instead I get these values:

```
array:3 [▼
          0 => "25"
          1 => "6"
      ]
 array:3 [▼
          0 => "32"
          1 => "6"
      ] 
array:3 [▼
          0 => "30"
          1 => "6"
      ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a php function like python's zip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815162/is-there-a-php-function-like-pythons-zip)

Comment: I didn't know we could do that @FedericoklezCulloca I had to try with the question and it works great ! https://3v4l.org/6PTgI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is change your foreach loop to this:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($medicine_order as $key=>$id) {
    $item = new Historyitem;
    $item->medicine_id = $id;
    $item->historyitem_quantity = $medicine_quantity[$key];
    $item->save();
    $count++;
}
```

Reason why you are getting wrong result is, your internal `foreach` loop, it iterates over every element of your `$medicine_quantity` array and every time it replaces the older value with new value, hence you are getting the value of last index i.e., "6" in final result.

Answer (score 3):

You need to process the `$medicine_quantity` values in the same order as the `$medicine_order` values, which you can do by matching the keys to each array. Try this instead:

```
foreach ($medicine_order as $key => $id) {
    $item = new Historyitem;
    $item->medicine_id = $id;
    $item->historyitem_quantity = $medicine_quantity[$key];
    $item->save();
    $count++;
}
```