# How to concatenate two arrays using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$browser = array("firefox", "opera", "edge");
$version = array("10", "12", "14");
```

I want to concatenate them such a way that the final array should be:

```
array(0=>array("name"=>"firefox", "version"=>"10"), 1=>array("name"=>"opera", "version"=>"12"), 2=>array("name"=>"edge", "version"=>"14"));
```

The code can contain any builtin or user defined function. I have tried using:

```
$browser = array("firefox","opera","edge");
$version = array("10","12","14");
foreach($browser as $key=>$values){
  if(!isset($array)){
    $array = array("name"=>$browser[$key],"version"=>$version[$key]);
  }else{
    $array = array($array,array("name"=>$browser[$key],"version"=>$version[$key]));
  }
}
print_r($array);
```

And the output I got was:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => firefox [version] => 10 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => opera [version] => 12 ) ) [1] => Array ( [name] => edge [version] => 14 ) )
```

Also note that this code is in PHP and should work for at least 10 arrays length data.

Comment: Just in case these separate arrays are coming from an HTML form post (as they often are in questions like this) you can name the inputs so that $_POST already has the final array you're trying to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just map the arrays:

```
$result = array_map(function($b, $v) {
                        return ['browser' => $b, 'version' => $v];
                    }, $browser, $version);
```

You can also use an array for dynamic keys:

```
$keys = ['browser', 'version'];
$result = array_map(function($b, $v) use($keys) {
                        return array_combine($keys, [$b, $v]);
                    }, $browser, $version);
```

However with your code just use the first format in the `if` and dynamically append `[]`:

```
foreach($browser as $key=>$values){
    $array[] = array("name"=>$browser[$key],"version"=>$version[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Reminded me of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815162/is-there-a-php-function-like-pythons-zip, but that doesn't include the keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($browser); $i++) {
  $result[] = array($browser[$i], $version[$i]); 
}
return $result;
```

Very simple - just loop through the one array and use indexes.