# Create Comma separated Array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am having an array like :

```
array
(
  ['fruit1'] => banana,
  ['fruit2'] => apple,
  ['fruit3'] => grapes,
  ['fruit4'] => orange 
)
```

And I want the array Like :

```
array(banana,apple,grapes,orange);
```

Please suggest how can I convert it.

Comment: what you tried so far... provide your tried code

Comment: I think if you take a gander at array functions in the PHP manual you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: Can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914105/2d-multidimensional-array-to-1d-array-in-php

Comment: I want comma separated value as : array(banana,apple,grapes,orange); I need this array to put this for generate CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php 
echo "<pre>";
$arr = array('fruit1'=>'banana','fruit2'=>'apple','fruit3'=>'grapes','fruit4'=>'orange');
$new = array_values($arr);
print_r($new);
```

For more info about `array_values` please read http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => banana
    [1] => apple
    [2] => grapes
    [3] => orange
)
```

Comment: I dont want these indexes.
I want comma separated value as : array(banana,apple,grapes,orange); I need this array to put this for generate CSV.

Comment: @NehaPareek if you print `array(banana,apple,grapes,orange);` the output is same as mine . `$new` is same as `array(banana,apple,grapes,orange);`

Answer (score 1):

use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/3t9Jn)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$new_array = array_values($your_array);
```

Note: You dont need commas after banana, apple and grapes in the main array.

Comment: I want comma separated value as : array(banana,apple,grapes,orange); I need this array to put this for generate CSV.

Comment: You cant put an array as a line in a csv. what you can do is make a `STRING` using your array.

`$string = implode(", ", array_values($your_array));`

The above should work