# php reassign array contents

Tags: php, arrays

any particular function or code to put this kind of array data

```
ori  [0] => 43.45,33,0,35 [1] => 74,10,0,22 [2] => 0,15,0,45 [3] => 0,0,0,340 [4] => 12,5,0,0 [5] => 0,0,0,0
```

to

```
new  [0] => 43.45,74,0,0,12,0 [1] => 33,10,15,0,5,0 [2] => 0,0,0,0,0,0, [3] => 35,22,45,340,0,0
```

As you can see, the first value from each ori are inserted into the new(0), the second value from ori are inserted into new(1) and so on

Comment: There won't be such built-in function, but you can create it yourself!

Comment: Need to iterate through this array by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially want to transpose - basically "turn" - an array. Your array elements are strings and not sub arrays, but those strings can be turned into sub arrays with [**`explode()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) before transposing. Then after transposing, we can turn the sub arrays back into strings with [**`implode()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to preserve the formatting you want.

Basically we want to go through each of your five strings of comma separated numbers one by one. We take each string of numbers and turn it into an array. To transpose we have to take each of the numbers from a string one by one and add the number to a new array. So the heart of the code is the inner [**`foreach()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Note how each number goes into a new sub array, since `$i` is increased by one between each number: `$new[$i++][] =$op;`

```
foreach($ori as $one) {
    $parts=explode(',',$one);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($parts as $op) {
        $new[$i++][] =$op;
    }

}
$i = 0;
foreach($new as $one) {
    $new[$i++] = implode(',',$one);
}

// print_r for $new is:
Array
(
    [0] => 43.45,74,0,0,12,0
    [1] => 33,10,15,0,5,0
    [2] => 0,0,0,0,0,0
    [3] => 35,22,45,340,0,0
)
```

[**Working example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dduqZx)

Answer (score 3):

If `$ori` is an array of arrays, this should work:

```
function transpose($array) {
    array_unshift($array, null);
    return call_user_func_array('array_map', $array);
}

$newArray = transpose($ori);
```

*Note: from [Transposing multidimensional arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797251/transposing-multidimensional-arrays-in-php)*

If $ori is not an array of arrays, then you'll need to convert it first (or use the example by Peter Ajtai), like this:

```
// Note: PHP 5.3+ only
$ori = array_map(function($el) { return explode(",", $el); }, $ori);
```

If you are using an older version of PHP, you should probably just use the other method!

Comment: Looks like you'd have to first do an explode, but this seems nice

Comment: Yeah, I should probably include an example of that.

Comment: To get `$newArray` back to an array of strings in PHP 5.3+ you can use `$newArray = array_map(function($el) { if (is_array($el)) return implode(",", $el); }, $newArray);` ---- Here' an example of the whole thing ==> http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ub3ryx