# php concat array values into new array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with arrays in it representing values in a database.

There are over 100 columns in the db table so the actual count is much higher than this example below of 6 values, the sub-array (Array within the array) index 0-5.

The columns are in each index of the sub-array and the rows are in each index of the main array.

Here is my main array with sub-arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => N
            [1] => N
            [2] => Y
            [3] => Y
            [4] => Y
            [5] => Y
)
 [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => N
            [1] => N
            [2] => Y
            [3] => Y
            [4] => N
            [5] => Y
)
[2] => Array
        (
            [0] => N
            [1] => N
            [2] => Y
            [3] => Y
            [4] => N
            [5] => Y
)
[3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Y
            [1] => Y
            [2] => Y
            [3] => Y
            [4] => Y
            [5] => Y
)
```

What I need to do is concat all the values of each sub index into one array like this:

```
Array
( 
            [0] => N,N,N,Y
            [1] => N,N,N,Y
            [2] => Y,Y,Y,Y
            [3] => Y,Y,Y,Y
            [4] => Y,N,N,Y
            [5] => Y,Y,Y,Y
)
```

There will always be the same number of columns (sub index) but there will be different amounts of rows (index).

Comment: As demonstrated by sevavietl's answer, this is a simple task of [transposing an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/797251/2943403).  The fact that comma-separated strings are desired is a supplemental step.

Comment: Duplicate with worse question details and worse answers versus this page: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7074080/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is get the data by column, you're in luck, there's a built in function for that. Its `array_column`.

So first, get the number of columns and simply use a for loop for that. Then just use `implode` and assign it inside a new container:

```
$new = array(); // container
$count = count($arr[0]); // get the number of colums
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    // get the data by column number ($i), then implode and push inside
    $new[] = implode(',', array_column($arr, $i));
}
```

Here's a sample [output](https://3v4l.org/M3uZN)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using explicit loops like `for` and `while`. Use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (it can take the variable mumber of arrays to traverse):

```
$result = array_map(function (...$column) {
    return implode(',', $column);
}, ...$array);
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/129b39fb8e324852e4a66a797d34304e64799390).

By the way, in [linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra) this is called [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of the matrix.

From PHP7.4 and higher, the same technique can be written as: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GXpU4))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn() => implode(',', func_get_args()),
        ...$array
    )
);
```

Or: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/61F9r))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn(...$column) => implode(',', $column),
        ...$array
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have defined `$column` as the total number of column in your db table. Use `array_column` to get the value according to the column key.

```
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $column; $i++) {
    $res = array_column($arr, $i);
    $result[] = implode(",", $res);
}
```

For more information about `array_column` function, check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

Oh, just to let you know that `array_column` function only works for PHP 5.5 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

check if this is what you want

```
$arr = array(//your array); 
$newArr = array(); //data wil lbe saved here
foreach($arr as $arr_one){
    $string = "";
    foreach($arr_one as $subArr){
        $string.=$subArr.",";
    }
    array_push($newArr,rtrim($string,','));
}

var_dump($newArr);
```