# Rotate an array of arrays clockwise 90 degrees

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, rotation, orientation

I would like to rotate the orientation of an array so that rows and columns are inverted.

For example, I want to convert this:

```
1     cat     calico
2     dog     collie
3     cat     siamese
4     dog     mutt
```

to this:

```
4       3        2         1
dog     cat      dog       cat
mutt    siamese  collie    calico
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Sounds like you want to transpose a multidimensional array:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797251/transposing-multidimensional-arrays-in-php

Comment: Can you show us some of your code please.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here, are you trying to display the information in a different way on the page? If so, this is not a PHP question, but rather an HTML/CSS question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can accomplish this:

```
function rotate_2d_array($array)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach (array_values($array) as $key => $sub_array)
    {
        foreach (array_values($sub_array) as $sub_key => $value)
        {
            if (empty($result[$sub_key]))
            {
                $result[$sub_key] = array($value);
            }
            else
            {
                array_unshift($result[$sub_key], $value);
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

And here is the test:

```
$a = array(
    array(1, 'cat','calico'),
    array(2, 'dog', 'collie'),
    array(3, 'cat', 'siamese'),
    array(4, 'dog', 'mutt')
);
print_r($a);

$b = rotate_2d_array($a);
print_r($b);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$initialData = array( 1 => array('cat', 'calico'),
                      2 => array('dog', 'collie'),
                      3 => array('cat', 'siamese'),
                      4 => array('dog', 'mutt'),
                    );

$transposedArray = call_user_func_array('array_map',array_merge(array(NULL),$initialData));

var_dump($transposedArray);
```

Note that it loses the array indexing though, and is simply a one-line variant of @Codler's response in the question linked by @Keith

Comment: This answer is not well explained.  Asking the OP and researchers to "trust our magic" doesn't empower them -- it makes them more dependent upon us to do their work for them.

Comment: This answer is performing "transposition", not clockwise rotation.  This answer is incorrect.  Incorrect result: https://3v4l.org/2q1Fk