# How to serialize multidimensional inputs with JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<form class="add_skill_form">
  <input type="hidden" name="skills[][skill_title]" value="Skill 1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="skills[][skill_level]" value="1" />

  <input type="hidden" name="skills[][skill_title]" value="Skill 2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="skills[][skill_level]" value="2" />
</form>
```

And I would like to serialize this with JQuery if possible, like so:

```
var loFormFields = $('.add_skill_form').serializeArray();
```

Now I don't get the params I would like, like so:

```
$_POST['skills'] = array
(
   0 => array('skill_title' => 'Skill 1', 'skill_level' => 1),
   1 => array('skill_title' => 'Skill 2', 'skill_level' => 2)
)
```

Anyone any clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try swapping your array indices - for instance, `name="skills[skill_title][]"`

Then, if you absolutely have to swap the indices back, [transpose the array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797251/transposing-multidimensional-arrays-in-php).

Comment: I think the problem is in the serializeArray function of JQuery!

Comment: Have you looked at the output of the serialization and then what $_POST['skills'] contains? You should be able to parse to an array from there.