# Array group by key PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following response from my PHP code.

```
Array
(
[customer] => 402
[carat] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 5
    )

[units] => Array
    (
        [0] => grams
        [1] => dwt
        [2] => dwt
    )

[weight] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 6
    )

[our_payout] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15
        [1] => 9
        [2] => 60
    )

[sale_payout] => Array
    (
        [0] => 18
        [1] => 12
        [2] => 180
    )

[hidden_carat] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 5
        [2] =>
    )

[hidden_unit] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 2
    )

[carat_scale_price] => Array
    (
        [0] =>
        [1] =>
        [2] =>
    )

[sales_id] => Array
    (
        [0] =>
        [1] =>
        [2] =>
    )

[currency_rate_id] => Array
    (
        [0] =>
        [1] =>
        [2] =>
    )

[gold_price_id] => Array
    (
        [0] =>
        [1] =>
        [2] =>
    )

[taget_percentage] =>
[reference] => 0
[notes] =>
[unit] => 0
[customer_id] => 402
[total_items] => 2
[submit] =>
)
```

And I want to join for `example [0] => grams` with `[0] => 5 [0] => 16` and so on.

Comment: We're not entirely sure what you're asking? Are you trying to do string concats?

Comment: I reckon you need to prepare the input array structure to be a complete matrix before trying to transpose.  Otherwise there is some ambiguity in how the `customer` and `carat` should be distributed in the result array.  (I suppose `customer` isn't terribly ambiguous, but as I said, filling the gaps will make transposing cleaner and more reliable.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Steve, I'm not really sure what you're asking for.  It looks like you want to transpose that matrix but only for some of the keys?  Here's something that might do what you're looking for, assuming that your original array above is in the variable $arr:

```
$lineItems = array();
$i = 0;
$allLineItemsHaveI = true;

while($allLineItemsHaveI) {
   $lineItems[$i] = array();
   foreach($arr as $key => $subArr) {
      if(array_key_exists($i, $subArr)) {
         $lineItems[$i][$key] = $subArr[$i];
      } else {
         $allLineItemsHaveI = false;
      }
   } 

   $i++;
}    

array_pop($lineItems);
```

This is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [carat] => 6
            [units] => grams
            [weight] => 5
            [our_payout] => 15
            [sale_payout] => 18
            [hidden_carat] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [carat] => 5
            [units] => dwt
            [weight] => 3
            [our_payout] => 9
            [sale_payout] => 12
            [hidden_carat] => 5
        )

)
```

Also, check this out: [Transposing multidimensional arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797251/transposing-multidimensional-arrays-in-php)