# Create indexed array of two-element subarrays from flat associative array

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to convert this array:

```
array(
  'A' => 'B',
  'C' => 'D',
)
```

To this array:

```
array(
  array(
    'A',
    'B',
  ),
  array(
    'C',
    'D',
  ),
)
```

Comment: This is effectively calling for the transposition of an array containing the keys and an array containing the values.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797251/transposing-multidimensional-arrays-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$source = array(
  'A' => 'B',
  'C' => 'D',
)

foreach ($source as $key => $value){
  $result[] = array($key, $value);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 5):

You are probably looking for the [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) (builds pairings based on existing arrays, see [*Example #4 Creating an array of arrays*](http://php.net/array_map#example-4633) on the manual page) and the [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) (all keys of an array) functions:

```
array_map(null, array_keys($array), $array));
```