# PHP merge multiple arrays in order of their value index

Tags: php, arrays, transpose, flatten, array-merge

I've found a lot of information on joining arrays together using `array_merge`, but I'm wondering how easy it is to merge multiple arrays in order of their value index, rather than simply joining them together.

For example, if we had the following three arrays:

```
$a = array('One','Two','Three','Four');
$b = array(1,2,3,4);
$c = array('i','ii','iii','iv');
```

Could we merge them into?:

```
One,1,i,Two,2,ii,Three,3,iii,Four,4,iv
```

Instead of:

```
One, Two, Three, Four, 1, 2, 3, 4, i, ii, iii, iv
```

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in function for this, just write a `for` loop.

Comment: what is the purpose? You are going to have to make your own custom merge function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write your custom function like this.

```
$a = array('One','Two','Three','Four');
$b = array(1,2,3,4);
$c = array('i','ii','iii','iv');

$count = max(count($a), count($b), count($c));
$newarray = array();

for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   if (isset($a[$i])) $newarray[] = $a[$i];
   if (isset($b[$i])) $newarray[] = $b[$i];
   if (isset($c[$i])) $newarray[] = $c[$i];
}

var_dump($newarray);
```

Comment: This assumes all the arrays are the same length.  Better to do `$count = max(count($a), count($b), count($c));` and then do an `isset()` on each array before attempting to add an index to `$newarray`

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick quite nicely. The arrays will always be identical in length in my application :)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't actually use this code due to readability, but it's cool that it works.

Make an array of arrays first

```
$a = array('One','Two','Three','Four');
$b = array(1,2,3,4);
$c = array('i','ii','iii','iv');
$arrays = [$a, $b, $c];
```

then

```
array_unshift($arrays, null);
$n = call_user_func_array('array_merge', call_user_func_array('array_map', $arrays));
print_r($n);
```

yields

```
Array
(
    [0] => One
    [1] => 1
    [2] => i
    [3] => Two
    [4] => 2
    [5] => ii
    [6] => Three
    [7] => 3
    [8] => iii
    [9] => Four
    [10] => 4
    [11] => iv
)
```

demo http://codepad.org/FdZKffPQ

it makes use of this matrix transpose method https://stackoverflow.com/a/3423692