# Combine data from several array to one array

Tags: php

I wrote a script that combines the results equally from several arrays. The script works well, but I would like to do it more easily. My knowledge of php programming is poor. I have a question for experienced programmers, do you have any idea how can I get the same result using a better solution?

My code:

```
<?php
$a = array('a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a');
$b = array('b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b');
$c = array('c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c');

$count = count(array_merge($a, $b, $c));

$results = array();
for ($i=1; $i<$count; $i++){

    if (isset($a[$i]) && !empty($a[$i])){ $results[] = $a[$i]; } 
    if (isset($b[$i]) && !empty($b[$i])){ $results[] = $b[$i]; } 
    if (isset($c[$i]) && !empty($c[$i])){ $results[] = $c[$i]; } 
}

print_r($results); // array(a, b, c, a, b, c ..)
?>
```

Comment: You are already doing the merge, why do it again? If your problem is removing empty cells just do a filter after the merge.

Comment: The point is that I have the same data in several arrays and I want to arrange it in the way it receives in my code

Comment: What is your expected output for the example given? `a,a,a,..,b,b,b,...c,c,c,...`?

Comment: a,b,c...a,b,c...a,b,c...

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386630/php-merge-multiple-arrays-in-order-of-their-value-index

Comment: it depends on what you want as the output look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394157/whats-the-difference-between-array-merge-and-array-array

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array('a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a');
$b = array('b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b');
$c = array('c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c');


for ($i=0; $i < max(count($a), count($b), count($c)) ; $i++) {
    foreach (array('a', 'b', 'c') as $l) {
        if (!isset($$l[$i]) || empty($$l[$i])) {continue; };
        $results[] = $$l[$i];
    };
}; 


print_r($results);
```

Please note that in your code, you started with $i = 1, whereas you probably wanted to start at $i = 0 (the first entry of an array is 0, not 1).

The code could be further improved depending on the requirements: if you only have 3 arrays, and it's not super important, that should do it