# loop to populate html table vertically

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a mysql query that returns an array of rows. How would i populate my html table using php vertically? there is no limit to how many columns i my HTML table allowed.

My MYSQL query returns about 40 columns per row.

```
MYSQL row1 =>  10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19
      row2 =>  20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29
      row3 =>  30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39
```

HTML output should look like this

```
   10 | 20 | 30
   11 | 21 | 31
   12 | 22 | 32
   13 | 23 | 33
   14 | 24 | 34
   15 | 25 | 35
   16 | 26 | 36
   17 | 27 | 37
   18 | 28 | 38
   19 | 29 | 39
```

this is my code, and it's displaying nothing.

```
$values = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 0,12";
$result = $_db->query($sql);

$numrows = $_db->num_rows($result);

$c = 1;
while ($c <= $numrows)
{
    $values['col_'.$c] = array(); 
    $c++;
}

$r = 1;

while ($row = $_db->fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $values['col_'.$c][$r] = $row;

    $r++; 
}
echo "<table border='1'>";


for ($r = 1; $r <= $numrows; $r++) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($c = 1; $c <= sizeof($values['col_1']); $c++) 
    { 
        echo "<td>".$values['col_'.$c][$r]."</td>"; 
    }
    echo "</tr>" ;
}
echo "</table>" ;
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong? or how to make it simpler? (i think there are too many while loops)

Comment: Just to clarify: A row from your mysql table contains the data for 1 column?

Comment: nope, 1 row returns 30 columns. and i want to display the 30 columns vertically.

Comment: In your example output, 10 till 19 are in 1 column (and 10 rows) of your html table. Is this data (10 till 19) in 1 row of your MYSQL table, or 10 rows of your MYSQL table?

Comment: `code`$numrows = $_db->num_rows($result);
//check here
if ($numrows > 0)
{
    //1 row
    $r = 1;

    while ($row = $_db->fetch_array($result))
    {
        //value row column  
        $values[$r] = $row; 
        
        //increase row
        $r++;
    }
    echo "<table border='1'>";

    //display row and columns
    $c = 0;
    
    foreach ($values as $row)
    {
     echo "<tr>";
     for ($r = 1; $r <= sizeof($row); $r++)
     {
         echo "<td>".$values[$r][$c]."</td>";
     }
     echo "</tr>";
        
     $c++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
}`code`

Comment: it still doesn't display ALL columns from the mysql query. it does display ALL rows from the mysql query tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is creating the php array from the mysql query, transposing the array (like you would transpose a matrix) and display it.

Transposing an array is a solved problem ([transposing multidimentional arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797251/transposing-multidimensional-arrays-in-php))

For the rest, it is pretty simple ... here is my code:

```
$res = mysqli_query(...);

$anarr = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res,$result_type=MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $anarr[] = $row;

}

// here is the transpose part
array_unshift($anarr, null);
$transposedarr = call_user_func_array('array_map', $anarr);
// end of the transpose part

echo '<table>';

foreach ($transposedarr as $r){
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($r as $c){
        echo '<td>'.$c.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: thank you! what does call_user_func_array() do? i read it on php.net but don't quite get it. and why array_unshift()? doesn't $anarr[] = $row; add to the array?

Comment: as you can see in the link I sent (just copy pasted since its better explained than what i would have come up with): "the first line inserts NULL as the first value of the array. The next line calls array_map with all the entries of $array as the parameters. So it's the same as calling array_map(NULL, $array[0], $array[1], $array[2], etc etc)." see the array_map documentation for how to construct an array of arrays, which can be easily performed by using NULL as the name of the callback function"

Comment: how do i echo the $key of the array before the $c ? my mysql queries results look like this array("name"=> bla, "id" => bla .... );

Comment: so i assume that you want to get the keys corresponding to each row like a row header.

Comment: so i assume that you want to get the keys corresponding to each row like a row header. The keys are lost when you use array_map. So, you need to get them before that. What I would do is $keys = array_keys($anarr[0]) before doing array_unshift(...) and echo them after echo '<tr>'. I would add an index before the first loop ($ind = 0), and replace echo '<tr>'; by echo '<tr><td>'.$keys[$ind].'</td>';$ind ++;

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning only one row in your while loop. Change that with below code:

```
while ($row = $_db->fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $values['col_'.$c][$r] = $row;
    $c++;
    $r++; 
}
```

Here you are assigning the value to `$value['col_1'][$r]`  and not increasing the value of `$c`. So at the end it override the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the problem by just saying

`$values[$rowIndex] = $columnArray`

So in this case

```
$values[0] = array( 10, 20, 30 );
$values[1] = array( 11, 21, 31 );
```

And then loop across each array

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
foreach( $values as $row )
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach( $row as $columnValue )
    {
        echo ..whatever..
    }
    echo "<tr>";
}
echo "</table>" ;
```

Or something along these lines. I just basically psuedo coded this though, I have no access to php interpreter right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything in a single loop. Additionally, at least for your purposes in this example, I don't understand why you're putting everything in an array and then echo, instead of echoing it directly.

e.g. (**tested**):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 0,12";
$result = $_db->query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>";

$tab = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_row())
{
    $tab[] = $row;
}

for( $i = 0, $l = count($tab[$i]); $i < $l; $i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    for( $j = 0, $m = count($tab); $j < $m; $j++){
        echo "<td>".$tab[$j][$i]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>" ;
}

echo "</table>";
```

**UPDATE**: I completely changed my code. I didn't get initially what you needed.

Does this code help you?

Comment: this displaying every row of the array horizontally. <tr>11|12|13</tr><tr>21|22|23</tr> and so on

Comment: uhm.. the output should be <tr><td>11</td><td><12</td><td>13</td></tr>.. and so on.. but I can't test it now. did you try it? for sure it can't be what you said, because there must be also some <td>s

Comment: @user2035819 did you test it?

Comment: yup, still displaying all horizontally.

Comment: I changed the code, now it should be what you're looking for.. check it out

Answer (score 0):

```
//while and foreach loop can do this
<?php 

$values = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 0,12";
$result = $_db->query($sql);

$numrows = $_db->num_rows($result);

//check here
if($numrows>0)
{
    //1 row
    $r = 1;
    //column
    $c=0;

    while ($row = $_db->fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        //value row column  
        $values[$r][$c] = $row; 

        //column == 3
        if($c==2)
        {
            //increase row
            $r++;
            //reset column
            $c = 0;

        }else{

            $c++;
        }
    }
    echo "<table border='1'>";


    //display row and columns
    foreach($values as $row)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$values[0]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$values[1]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$values[2]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>" ;
    }
    echo "</table>" ;
}
```

Comment: $value is an $row what you want to print in that $row.. you didn't mention anything.. $value[0]['field_name of your choice];

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would tackle it. The most difficult part is preparing the structure in which you prepare the table. It uses the following syntax: `$somearray[] = $x`, which appends `$x` to array `$somearray`. `implode()` concats an array together with a string you define. Last but not least, you were using `mysql_fetch_assoc`, which returns an associative array (`Array( [column1] => "val1" );` etc). You want a numbered array instead for these kind of operations. This can be accomplished with `mysql_fetch_array` with a second argument of `MYSQL_NUM`.

```
$arrayOfRows = Array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 0,12";
$result = $_db->query($sql);

$firstrun = true;
while( $row = $_db->fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM) ) {
  #Setup structure on first run
  if( $firstrun ) {
    $firstrun = false;
    for( $i = 0; $i < count( $row ); $i++ ) {
      $arrayOfRows[$i] = Array();
    }
  }

  #Each field in this mysql row needs to be in a different html row
  foreach( $row as $k => $v ) {
    $arrayOfRows[$k][] = $v;
  }
}

#Now simply print it
echo '<table>';

foreach( $arrayOfRows as $k => $row ) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . implode( '</td><td>', $row ) . '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 

$arr = array(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), array(10,11 etc . . .

for($i = 0; $i < 9; ++ $i){

    for($x = 0; $x < $num_rows; ++ $x){

         echo $arr[$x][$i];

    }
    echo '<br/>';

}

?>
```

U may replace 9 with number of columns in tables

I not shure what it this code correct (can't test now), but i think it can help you
Sorry if i do something wrong, i just try to help