# I have 5 arrays each array contains 10 values, I want to invert these arrays into 10 arrays and each array contains 5 values using php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, nsmutablearray

For Example:

```
$array_1 = [1,'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];
$array_2 = [2,'aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff','gg','hh','ii'];
$array_3 = [3,'aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee','fff','ggg','hhh','iii'];
$array_4 = [4,'aaaa','bbbb','cccc','dddd','eeee','ffff','gggg','hhhh','iiii'];
$array_5 = [5,'aaaaa','bbbbb','ccccc','ddddd','eeeee','fffff','ggggg','hhhhh',   
'iiiii'];
```

Using PHP Script I want to convert it into

```
$array_1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
$array_2 = ['a','aa','aa a','aa aa','aa aa a'];
$array_3 = ['b','bb','bb b','bb bb','bb bb b'];
$array_4 = ['c','cc','cc c','cc cc','cc cc c']; 
$array_5 = ['d','dd','dd d','dd dd','dd dd d']; 
$array_6 = ['e','ee','ee e','ee ee','ee ee e'];
.
...
$array_10 = ['i','ii','iii','iiii','iiiii'];
```

Can anyone provide me a solution for that.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/797251/3933332

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post the code, then we can help. Stackoverflow is about helping code, not free programmers

Comment: I am getting x no of dynamic arrays with y no of values I needed a php script to convert it into Y no of arrays with x no of values that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can use `array_map` like as

```
$array_1 = [1,'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];
$array_2 = [2,'aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff','gg','hh','ii'];
$array_3 = [3,'aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee','fff','ggg','hhh','iii'];
$array_4 = 
[4,'aaaa','bbbb','cccc','dddd','eeee','ffff','gggg','hhhh','iiii'];
$array_5 =
[5,'aaaaa','bbbbb','ccccc','ddddd','eeeee','fffff','ggggg','hhhhh',   
'iiiii'];

$result = array_map(null,$array_1,$array_2,$array_3,$array_4,$array_5);
print_r($result);
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/mY6pd)

Comment: Thanks for answered me... it work statically.
What if No of arrays (i.e. $array_1, $array_2..... $array_n) is dynamic ?

Comment: Then probably check the answer that @Rizier123 has suggested for you