# Insert database rows from columns of data from associative array of indexed arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, transpose, insert-query

I have an array called `$works` which looks like this:

```
[
    'type' => [1, 5],
    'description' => [2, 6],
    'hours' => [3, 7],
    'amount' => [4, 8]
]
```

I need to send all values to Database (MySQL) in two iterations. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO `works` (`type`, `description`, `hours`, `amount`) VALUES (works[type][0], works[decsription][0], works[hours][0], works[amount][0]);

INSERT INTO `works` (`type`, `description`, `hours`, `amount`) VALUES (works[type][1], works[description][1], works[hours][1], works[amount][1]);
```

Comment: Either use a for loop and then use a counter variable to access each value in the loop or transpose the array and then use a foreach loop

Comment: Darren - I know it's not taht hard  but somehow I have been struggling for good three hours trying different loop variations. Of course I tried $i++

Comment: @ Rizier123 - mate, thanks a bunch!!! freaking convenient solution in my case!!!
"transpose the array and then use a foreach loop"

Comment: good threaD on the array transposing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797251/transposing-multidimensional-arrays-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i=0; $i<count($works['type']); $i++) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `works` (`type`, `decsripion`, `hours`, `amount`) VALUES ('{works[type][$i]}', '{works[description][$i]}', '{works[hours][$i]}', '{works[amount][$i]}')";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

That is provided that you have already connected and selected a database.
There are better ways of doing this but this depends on framework you are using. For example, you might want to escape these values before trying to insert them into database.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try this.

```
<?php
$works = array('type'=>array(1,5),'description'=>array(2,6),'hours'=>array(3,7),'amount'=>array(4,8));
    $insert_query = 'INSERT INTO works(type,description,hours,amount) values ';
    for($i=0; $i<count($works['type']); $i++) {
                $insert_query .= "('".$works['type'][$i]."','".$works['description'][$i]."','".$works['hours'][$i]."','".$works['amount'][$i]."')," ;

    }

    $query = rtrim($insert_query, ',');
    //echo $query;
    if(!mysqli_query($con,$query)){
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }else{
        echo "record added";
    }
```

In this i have used `bulk insert into` you can `echo` `query` if you want to see the `query`. According to your question I have assumed that all `array` means `type`, `description` etc are of same `length` so i used `$works['type']` to calculate the `for` `loop` steps

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a prepared statement before entering your loop.
2. Count the number of columns by accessing the `type` subarray and counting its elements.
3. Bind the integer values (accessed using the counter variable `$i`) to the prepared statement.
4. Execute the prepared statement (you can check the affected rows if you like)

Code: ([Demo](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/b854637706829d93304fbd6fdbbf7e68/php/php8/abc7d5db22eb98e1be3b993ae185adf7/))

```
$works = [
    'type' => [1, 5],
    'description' => [2, 6],
    'hours' => [3, 7],
    'amount' => [4, 8]
];

if (!empty($works['type'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO works (type, description, hours, amount)
            VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    for ($i = 0, $count = count($works['type']); $i < $count; ++$i) {
        $stmt->bind_param(
            "iiii",
            $works['type'][$i],
            $works['description'][$i],
            $works['hours'][$i],
            $works['amount'][$i]
        );
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
var_export($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM works")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'type' => '1',
    'description' => '2',
    'hours' => '3',
    'amount' => '4',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'type' => '5',
    'description' => '6',
    'hours' => '7',
    'amount' => '8',
  ),
)
```