# How to use an array of arrays with array_map(...) in PHP?

Tags: php, ellipsis, variadic, variadic-functions

The PHP function [`array_map(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) expects a callback as first parameter (or `null` for [creating an array of arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#example-5562)) and a variable number of array arguments, e.g.:

```
$foo => array_map(null, $bar, $buz);
```

Now I have a case, where I need to pass to `array_map(...)` a variable number of arrays. I cannot hard-code this, since the arrays for the `array_map(...)`'s input are generated dynamically.

```
function performSomeLogicAndGetArgumentsForMyFunction() {
    ...
    return ['bar' => [...], 'buz' => [...]];
}
$foo = array_map(null, performSomeLogicAndGetArgumentsForMyFunction());
```

It doesn't work this way, since `array_map(...)` expects *a variable number of array* and not *an array of arrays*.

Is there a solution for this? **How can I keep the call flexible and pass a variable number of arguments to the `array_map(...)`?** (It also applies to every other variadic function I cannot manipulate.)

Comment: Take a look at `call_user_func_array()`

Comment: Thank you guys! Yes, sure, it's just an array and can be easily unpackt/iterated.

Comment: Sorry, I formulated the question wrong. The problem is actually with "re-passing" the arguments, e.g. to the `array_map(...)`. I've just edited the question.

Comment: I've corrected / completely rewritten the question.

Comment: [The canonical Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/797251/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an array of arrays, and you want to map over the innermost of those arrays. You can use [argument unpacking](http://lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator) for this:

```
function say($n, $m) {
    return "The number $n is called $m in Spanish";
}
function arrays() {
    return [
        [ 1, 2, 3 ],
        [ 'uno', 'dos', 'tres' ],
    ];
}
print_r(
    array_map('say', ...arrays())
);
```

[See it online at 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/EOXYL)

Alternatively, you could use `call_user_func_array` as mentioned in the [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking) at a measurable run-time cost:

```
print_r(
    call_user_func_array(
        'array_map',
        array_merge(array ('say'), arrays())
    )
);
```

[See it online at 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/ivb0Q)

Either of these patterns can implement variadic forms of common methods. For example, to emulate `vsprintf` one can use:

```
sprintf('%s %s', ...['Hello', 'World']);
call_user_func_array('sprintf', array_merge(['%s, %s'], ['Hello', 'World']));
```

Answer (score -3):

As a last resort, use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

```
//build you array of array variable names with the dynamic content coming in.
$arrays = ['$foo', '$bar', '$baz'];

$str = implode(', ', $arrays);
eval("\$map = array_map(null, $str);");

print_r($map);
```

Beware never to send un-sanitized input to eval.

[See it working](https://3v4l.org/EAO5g)

Comment: This is working code that has been tested and it answers the question of having a variable number of unknown arrays to pass to the array_map function. If you down vote at least leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: FYI, I dv'ed this answer (and voted to delete) because there is no compelling reason to use `eval()` when there is ANY alternative (and there are a few).