# Parse comma separated string, split array into chunks, then transpose

Tags: php, arrays, grouping, transpose, chunks

What is the best way to echo out an array where the values are grouped:

```
Array (
[0] => Service, Service, Service
[1] => 27 february, 2017, 27 march, 2017, 27 april, 2017
[2] => 08:00, 08:00, 08:00
)
```

If I want the result to be:

```
Service, 27 february, 2017 at 08:00.
Service, 27 march, 2017 at 08:00.
Service, 27 april, 2017 at 08:00.
```

**This is what I have come up with so far:**

```
<?php
$string = "Service, Service, Service, 8 mars, 2017, 22 mars, 2017, 5 april, 2017, 08:00, 08:00, 08:00";

$pattern = '/(\d+) (\w+), (\d+)/i'; //remove comma before year
$replacement = '${1} $2 $3';
$fixed = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
 
$array = explode(', ', $fixed); 

$i=0;

foreach($array as $value) {
    echo $value.", ";
    $i++;

    if ($i == 3) {
        echo '<br>';
        $i = 0;
    }
}    
?>
```

The output:

```
Service, Service, Service, 
8 mars 2017, 22 mars 2017, 5 april 2017, 
08:00, 08:00, 08:00,
```

So they are still in the wrong order... I just cant figure out how to sort the array and group the values I want one after another instead of in a row.

Comment: How is this array formed?It might be easier to start there

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/797251/3933332

Comment: Mihai: I use a wordpress plugin so i don´t want to hassle with to core code. I am given a varible that i want to render in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as the number of rows is known, it only takes:

1. a regex to split the string on comma-spaces which immediately follow a one-or-more digits or a word starting with an uppercase letter,
2. a call of `array_chunk()` and
3. `array_map()` (with a null callback and data spreading) to "transpose" the data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YT6XN))

```
$string = "Service, Service, Service, 8 mars, 2017, 22 mars, 2017, 5 april, 2017, 08:00, 08:00, 08:00";

$rows = 3;

var_export(
    array_map(
        null,
        ...array_chunk(
            preg_split('/(?:[A-Z][a-z]+|\d+)\K, /', $string),
            $rows
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: That did the trick @mickmackusa, thank you for taking the time and help me!
All that is missing now is a count on the array so the function can be feed with to correct amount of rows, but that´s not going to be a problem :)