# Transpose data in an associative array of indexed arrays

Tags: php, arrays, format, transpose

I'm not sure how to search for the problem I'm facing, so that's why I'm asking here.

I want to know if there is a native php-function to transform following array I get from a html-form:

#### Original Array

```
$array = [
  'product_template_id' => [
    '0' => '1',
    '1' => '2'
  ],
  'amount' => [
    '0' => '50',
    '1' => '100'
  ]
]
```

#### Desired Array

```
$array = [
  '0' => [
    'product_template_id' => '1',
    'amount' => '50'
  ],
  '1' => [
    'product_template_id' => '2',
    'amount' => '100'
  ]
]
```

I know this can be done with a loop, but that's not what I'm asking for.

PS(not my main question, just a sidequestion): How can I bulk format code in stackoverflow? Is it always 4 spaces? How can I perform the formatting quicker?

edit: PS is not the main question, it is more of a sidenote which has already been answered by @RiggsFolly

Comment: No, there is not any native function to do this. You have to use the exists PHP function and adding some logic (for loop etc....)

Comment: Format = `CTRL+K`

Comment: You could make your own function if you needed to this often enough.

Comment: You can do something like this, its all one time, use sublime IDE, install plugin codeFormatter from package installer and create one dummy.php file, paste your code in that, then CTRL + ALT + F for formatting the code and copy that code from there, paste it in SO question and then select code you want to format and press CTRL + K. Thats it.

Comment: what is the real issue? just formatting spaces? use your text editor

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i think the question is clear. Its about reformatting the original array into the desired array using a programmatic approach with native php array functions.

Comment: @DominikVogt, good luck with that

Comment: Just use [`flipDiagonally()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/797268/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as prove of concept you can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
// For < PHPv5.6
// $zip = call_user_func_array('array_map', array_merge([null], $array));
$zip = array_map(null, ...array_values($array));
$result = array_map(function ($item) use ($keys) {
    return array_combine($keys, $item);
}, $zip);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8826d9585dc88da46c2d7277cd98775ba2108b12).

But in practice, there is too much overhead for so simple problem.

**EDIT:**
Here I am *zipping* (getting one corresponding element from each array and creating an array of this elements) all child arrays. It is done with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) using its property:

> An interesting use of this function is to construct an array of arrays, which can be easily performed by using NULL as the name of the callback function

As [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) can take an arbitrary number of arrays, I supply them to it with ['...' splat operator](https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator).

Answer (score 0):

This does what you need!

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($array['amount']); $x ++) {
    $arr[$x] = [
        'product_template_id' => $array['product_template_id'][$x],
        'amount' => $array['amount'][$x],
    ];
}
```

See here for a working example https://3v4l.org/dokHK

Comment: :D :D :D :D :D Read last line of OP. It is not the question for which you gave answer.

Comment: :-P Haha I see it now. Sure it could be done without a loop if your array always had the same length, but that won't be the case will it?

Comment: *How can I bulk format code in stackoverflow? Is it always 4 spaces? How can I perform the formatting quicker?* This is question. Op said, "I know this can be done with a loop, but that's not what I'm asking for.". So he knows how to do it, he wants to format code in SO. OP don't need code at all. OP needs steps or way to format code in SO.

Comment: Actually I'd like to know that too, this 4 spaces nonsense is wasting precious time!

Comment: highlight text to be formatted and press `CTRL + K`

Comment: Yes thats simple one, if needs more formatting like IDE, then follow my complete comment.