# Max Must be In Array

Tags: php

hellom im new on php, and i have some trouble with my code

this message error

> Message: max(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array

for sum(value) i don't have troubles. as you can see on this images.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eDfj.png)

But, when I tried to get the max value, but instead got an error like this.
[image2 error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsmHn.png)

this my error script (for find max value)

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
   {
      $pembagi[$i] = 0;
         for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
            {
               $pembagi[$i] = $pembagi[$i] + max($alternatifkriteria[$j][$i]);
            }
    }
```

and this my good script for find sum(value)

```
 for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
    {
       $pembagi[$i] = 0;
          for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
             {
                $pembagi[$i] = $pembagi[$i] + ($alternatifkriteria[$j][$i]);
             }
     }
```

can someone help me? i need to get max(value)
like this image
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvW7K.png)

this my array

```
$kriteria = [C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6];
$alternatif = [ALT1,ALT2,ALT,ALT4,ALT5,ALT6,ALT7];
arrayValue = (
[ALT1][C1] = 5
[ALT1][C2] = 1
[ALT1][C3] = 5
[ALT1][C4] = 2
[ALT1][C5] = 1
[ALT1][C6] = 5
[ALT2][C1] = 2
[ALT2][C2] = 4
[ALT2][C3] = 2
[ALT2][C4] = 5
[ALT2][C5] = 4
[ALT2][C6] = 4
[ALT3][C1] = 1
[ALT3][C2] = 4
[ALT3][C3] = 2
[ALT3][C4] = 5
[ALT3][C5] = 2
[ALT3][C6] = 4
[ALT4][C1] = 2
[ALT4][C2] = 4
[ALT4][C3] = 4
[ALT4][C4] = 5
[ALT4][C5] = 4
[ALT4][C6] = 2
[ALT5][C1] = 5
[ALT5][C2] = 4
[ALT5][C3] = 4
[ALT5][C4] = 1
[ALT5][C5] = 2
[ALT5][C6] = 4
[ALT6][C1] = 4
[ALT6][C2] = 4
[ALT6][C3] = 2
[ALT6][C4] = 5
[ALT6][C5] = 2
[ALT6][C6] = 4
[ALT7][C1] = 4
[ALT7][C2] = 2
[ALT7][C3] = 2
[ALT7][C4] = 5
[ALT7][C5] = 2
[ALT7][C6] = 1
);
```

Comment: It looks like `$alternatifkriteria[$j][$i]` isn't an array, but rather a single value in the array. Are you trying to find the max of all the values in the entire array? Or the max of the values in each row or column? The `max` function expects an array as its first parameter when only one parameter is passed (it doesn't make much sense to find the max of just one singular value).

Comment: what do you expect `max()` to return if you pass only one particular value as an argument? php interprets when one argument passed, that it should be an array to find the max element. Do you have another opinion?

Comment: @Nathan i need to find max value for  each column.I just added the results I wanted. see the latest updates

Comment: @Alex the most important point is how to get the max value, and I am confused to do it.

Comment: provide your array sample and expected result value or output

Comment: Please add the array you're using for testing to your question.

Comment: @Alex for result output i have add it before, and now i add my array

Comment: @Nathan I just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to include the existing value in the `max` computation:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
   {
      $pembagi[$i] = 0;
         for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
            {
               $pembagi[$i] = max($pembagi[$i], $alternatifkriteria[$j][$i]);
            }
    }
```

**Update**

Another way of doing this is to transpose the array (using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797251/transposing-multidimensional-arrays-in-php)) and then you can use [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and [`max`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) to get the sum and maximum value for each `$kriteria` value:

```
// get the values with numeric keys...
$akv = array_values($alternatifkriteria);
// so we can unpack them to transpose the array...
$akt = array_map(null, ...$akv);
// now we can just sum and take the max of each column
$sums = array_map(function ($v) { return array_sum($v); }, $akt);
$maxs = array_map(function ($v) { return max($v); }, $akt);
print_r($sums);
print_r($maxs);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 23 [1] => 23 [2] => 21 [3] => 28 [4] => 17 [5] => 24 )
Array ( [0] => 5  [1] => 4  [2] => 5  [3] => 5  [4] => 4  [5] => 5 )
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/6Jq0H)

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is not clear but probably this is something that can help you to move one step forward:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++) {
      $pembagi[$i] = max($alternatifkriteria[$i]);
}
```

**UPDATE** Here is another approach

```
 $j = 0;
 foreach ($alternatif as $column) {
     $pembagi[$j] = max(array_column($alternatifkriteria,$column));
     $j++;
 }
```

Comment: If the goal is not clear then please assist the new member in improving the question.

Comment: got error : array_column() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: error Message: max(): Array must contain at least one element

Answer (score 0):

because of your main goal is for show max value for each row so, this code will help you, this code dont use max but the goal same as what you need.

```
$pembagi = array();
       for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
          {
             $pembagi [$i] = 0;
             for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
                {
                   if ($j == 0) 
                      { 
                         $pembagi [$i] = $alternatifkriteria[$j][$i];
                      }
                   else 
                      {
                         if ($pembagi [$i] < $alternatifkriteria[$j][$i])
                            {
                               $pembagi [$i] = $alternatifkriteria[$j][$i];
                            }
                      }
                  }
             }
```