# PHP multi-dimensional array, merge duplicate keys into new arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array:

```
Array (
  [ids] => Array ( 
    [0] => e348ae92
    [1] => 193ba701
    [2] => 58695854
  )
  [name] => Array (
    [0] => Customers
    [1] => Suppliers
    [2] => Users
  )
  [subs] => Array (
    [0] => 614 
    [1] => 65
    [2] => 99
  )
)
```

I want to take each array key and turn it into a it's own array e.g.

```
array(
  [0] = array(
    [0] => e348ae92
    [1] => custommers
    [2] => 614
  )
  [1] = array(
    [0] => 193ba701
    [1] => Suppliers
    [2] => 65
  )
  [2] = array (
    [0] => 58695854
    [1] => Users
    [2] => 99
  )
)
```

I have looked at array_merge, array_combine and a few other things but I have been unsuccessful so far, any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the raw array which gives above output?

Comment: Welcome! Do you have same numbers of elements in each ids, name and subs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transposing multidimensional arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797251/transposing-multidimensional-arrays-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_map`

```
 $f = array_map(null, $a['ids'], $a['name'], $a['subs']);
 print_r($f);
```

Working example:https://3v4l.org/dDG0Y-