# Populating associative array values from other arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

If I have separate arrays w/ values for "questions" and "answers" like so:

`var_dump($questions)`

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Question 1' (length=10)
  1 => string 'Question 2' (length=10)
```

`var_dump($answers)`

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Answer 1' (length=10)
  1 => string 'Answer 2' (length=10)
```

How can I use these arrays to populate the values of a "master" associative array w/ keys for "question" and "answer" so I can then use a foreach loop to easily output the question/answer pairs? I'm trying to loop over each of the `$questions` and `$answers` arrays to populate values of a `$results` array- I've tried

```
foreach ( $questions as $question ) {
    $results[] = ['question' => $question];
}
```

and this creates separate items for each question, but I'm not sure how to add the "answer" values into the same array items to create the pairs. Thank you for any assistance here.

Comment: This question does not have a clear [mcve] because you didn't explicitly state the desired output structure from the sample input.  Mentioning "tips" after receiving an answer is not helpful to the page and usually wastes volunteers' time by forcing them to refactor their advice.

Comment: If you are seeking data transposition [Demo](https://3v4l.org/V1OPg), we have a canonical page for that too.  [Dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/797251/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I'm understanding the question correctly, but the [array_combine()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function may do what you want.

```
$master = array_combine($questions, $answers);
```

This will give you:

```
[
    'question 1' => 'answer 1',
    'question 2' => 'answer 2',
    'question 3' => 'answer 3',
]
```

Then you can do:

```
foreach ($master as $question => $answer) {
    ...
}
```

Note, this implies that questions are unique.

If instead, you want an indexed array of associative arrays, you could do something like:

```
$master = [];
foreach (array_combine($questions, $answers) as $question => $answer) {
    $master[] = [
        'question' => $question,
        'answer' => $answer,
    ];
}
```

This will give you:

```
[
    [
        'question' => 'question 1',
        'answer' => 'answer 1',
    ],
    [
        'question' => 'question 2',
        'answer' => 'answer 2',
    ],
    [
        'question' => 'question 3',
        'answer' => 'answer 3',
    ],
]
```

Or, more traditionally:

```
$master = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($questions); $i++) {
    $master[] = [
        'question' => $questions[$i],
        'answer' => $answers[$i],
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is great- thank you @alex-howansky; `array_combine` looks to be what I was missing. One other question- if I have a third element to add for each- e.g. "tip" ($tips) so each item would have a "question", "answer" and "tip", how would that affect the `array_combine` loop in your answer?

Comment: Since the key => value nature of an associative array implies a pair (i.e., just two data items), you couldn't use array_combine -- you'd have to use the for() loop as shown in the 3rd example.