# PHP: Packing different array values

Tags: php, arrays, transpose

`$_POST` is equal to:

```
Array
(
    [time_start] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00:00
            [1] => 02:00
        )

    [time_end] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03:00
            [1] => 05:00
        )

    [time_teach] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03:00
            [1] => 00:00
        )

    [submit] => 
)
```

And we are going to create the following output:

```
$data = [
    [
        "time_start" => $_POST["time_start"][0],
        "time_end" => $_POST["time_end"][0],
        "time_teach" => $_POST["time_teach"][0],
    ],
    [
        "time_start" => $_POST["time_start"][1],
        "time_end" => $_POST["time_end"][1],
        "time_teach" => $_POST["time_teach"][1],
    ],
];
```

One of my solution for this one:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST["time_start"] as $i => $time_start) {
    if (!isset($_POST["time_end"][$i]) ||
        !isset($_POST["time_teach"][$i]) ||
        // trim($_POST["time_start"][$i]) === "" ||
        // trim($_POST["time_end"][$i]) === "" ||
        // trim($_POST["time_teach"][$i]) === ""
    ) {
        continue;
    } else {
        // $time_start = trim($time_start);
        // $time_ends[$i] = trim($time_ends[$i]);
        // $time_teachs[$i] = trim($time_teachs[$i]);

        $row_item = [
            "time_start" => $time_start,
            "time_end" => $_POST["time_end"][$i],
            "time_teach" => $_POST["time_teach"][$i],
        ];
        $data[] = $row_item;
    }
}
?>
```

I am aware it's possible to do it easily by a foreach and getting other value by foreach keys.
But I am looking for the best solution. I guess maybe **PHP** has a **built-in** function that can do this job like **magic**!

I am looking for other ideas about this problem. Which may teach me something new.

Answer (score 1):

if you want short this statement, can you write these such:

```php
<?php


$post = [
    
    'time_start'=>
       [
           0=> '00:00',
           1=> '02:00'
        ],

    'time_end' => 
        [
            0 => '03:00',
            1 => '05:00'
        ],

    'time_teach' => 
        [
            0 => '03:00',
            1 => '00:00'
        ]

     ];

array_walk($post['time_start'],function($v,$k) use (&$data,$post){
    
    if(!isset($post['time_end'][$k])) return false;
    $data[] = [
        'time_start' => $v,
        'time_end' => $post['time_end'][$k]
    ];
});

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

A loop variant may be

```
$mappedArray = [];
foreach ($_POST as $key => $times) {
    foreach($times as $index => $time) {
        $mappedArray[$index][$key] = $time; 
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't need this redundant answer.  Please close duplicate pages instead of answering them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/797268/2943403

Answer (score 1):

The task can also be formulated as transposing a matrix (swapping rows and columns). There are ready-made functions for this. Example:

```
function array_transpose(array $a) {
  $r = array();
  foreach($a as $keyRow => $subArr) {
    foreach($subArr as $keyCol => $value) $r[$keyCol][$keyRow] = $value;
  }
  return $r;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/Seolg

Comment: We don't need this redundant answer.  Please close duplicate pages instead of answering them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/797268/2943403