# Restructure 2d array so that column values become row values (transpose but preserve first level keys)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping, transpose

The situation is as follows. I have a parent array which looks like the following:

```
$parent = [
    1 => ['test1', 'test2'],
    2 => ['test1_1', 'test2_2'],
];
```

I would like to group the data by column.

Desired result:

```
[
    1 => ['test1', 'test1_1'],
    2 => ['test2', 'test2_2'],
]
```

1 parent array called parent contains 2 arrays inside. I want to combine these two so that they have the same values as stated above. So this would mean that the arrays should be combined based on index number.

Since I do not make use of string keys, how would I accomplish this? I believe that there is no build in function available for this situation.

I would imagine that I could start beginning to create a new array and use a for loop through the parent array.

I tried the [array-combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function however, this is NOT displaying the results I want.

```
[
    1 => ['test1' => 'test1_1', 'test2' => 'test2_2'
]
```

Comment: `array_combine` is for creating an associative array from an array of keys and an array of values. What you want has nothing to do with that.

Comment: This is basically just transposing the array, not merging anything.

Comment: When performing this "transposition", are the first level keys actually important to preserve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to preserve those first level keys, you can re-apply them after [tranposing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/797251/2943403).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lk5gq))

```
var_export(
    array_combine(array_keys($parent), array_map(null, ...$parent))
);
```

Otherwise, you can just [transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/797251/2943403) and accept the re-indexed first level keys.  Honestly, I can't see any good reason to preserve the first level keys because by transposing, you remove the initial association between first level keys and the row values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5E9fr))

```
var_export(
    array_map(null, ...$parent)
);
```

If these techniques do not suit your actual project data, then we will need a more realistic sample array to be provided in your question body.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the keys of the top-level array. Then use the current index of the iteration to get the corresponding columns of the nested arrays.

```
$result = [];
foreach (array_keys($parent) as $i => $k) {
    $result[$k] = array_column($parent, $i);
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/jbU1hl)

This assumes the number of rows is the same as the number of columns. It's not clear what you expect the result to be if that's not true.