# Transpose array with 3 levels while retaining middle level (associative key)

Tags: php, arrays, transpose

I want to combine these arrays in a new array based on the same key number for creating tables. This is my code.

```
$arr3 = array();

print '<pre>';
print_r($bonus_table);
print '</pre>';

foreach($bonus_table as $key => $row) {
    $arr3 = array_merge($row['cells'],$arr3);
}

return $arr3;
```

And this is the output from my code. Basically this is the current structure of array:

```
Array
  (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [cells] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => DEPOTS
                            [1] => PRICES
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [cells] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 50
                            [1] => 25
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [cells] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 100
                            [1] => 50
                        )

                )
)
```

But I want to convert the above output with the below structure. The desired array should look like this:

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [cells] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => DEPOTS
                            [1] => 50
                            [2] => 100
                        )

                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [cells] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => PRICES
                            [1] => 25
                            [2] => 50
                        )
                )
         )
```

Comment: what is `$row['cells']`?

Comment: _"I have these arrays list:"_ - that only shows us your data, but not what variable(s) this is actually contained in. Please provide a proper [mre] when asking this kind of question.

Comment: Sorry, I did some changes in my post. I hope to explained better now.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your `foreach` loop with the below will produce the data you are after:

```
$arr3 = [
    [
        'cells' => ['Depots']
    ],
    [
        'cells' => ['Prices']
    ]
];

foreach ($bonus_table as $input) {
    if (is_numeric($input['cells'][0]) && is_numeric($input['cells'][1])) {
        $output_array[0]['cells'][] = $input['cells'][0];
        $output_array[1]['cells'][] = $input['cells'][1];
    }
}
```

Demo: https://onlinephp.io/c/06b36

Here we are looping through the input array (`$bonus_table`) and collecting data in an output array (`$arr3`).

Answer (score 0):

You simply could use `array_column`

```php
<?php

$bonus_table = [];
$bonus_table[]['cells'] = ["DEPOTS", "PRICES"];
$bonus_table[]['cells'] = [50, 25];
$bonus_table[]['cells'] = [100, 50];

$formattedArray = [];

// The bonus_table first level could be useless
$cellsArray = array_column($bonus_table, 'cells');

foreach($cellsArray as $key => $row) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $row)) {
        $formattedArray[]["cells"] = array_column($cellsArr, $key);
    }
}
```

outout

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cells] => Array
                (
                    [0] => DEPOTS
                    [1] => 50
                    [2] => 100
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cells] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PRICES
                    [1] => 25
                    [2] => 50
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have 3 levels in your array and the middle level uses `cells` as the key which needs to be retained, [array transposition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/797251/2943403) can be done swiftly without out any function calls by nesting a loop inside of another.

For the record, I don't see a lot of value in having the redundant `cells` level in your array structure.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OZZ2o))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as ['cells' => $data]) {
    foreach ($data as $i => $v) {
        $result[$i]['cells'][] = $v;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```